# @PreDestroy em @ViewScoped

Tags: java-ee, jsf-2.2

Percebi que o @PreDestroy em beans com escopo @ViewScoped só é chamado se a sessão que estava ativa expirar ou se eu forçar um redirecionamento de página (?faces-redirect=true). Sem essas condições, o bean com esse escopo nunca é destruído, e toda vez que eu entrar na página o bean é novamente criado.

1 - É problemático o bean nunca ser destruído e sempre ser criado toda vez que a página é acessada?

2 - É válido eu forçar a destruição do bean usando redirecionamento?

3 - Qual a vantagem do @ViewScoped sobre @SessionScoped nesse contexto?

Comment: Existe um bug em relação ao comportamento que falou, o `@preDestroy` só é chamado quando a sessão expira, gerando memory leak. Disseram que ele foi consertado na versão 2.2 da especificação, em 2012 (https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-905). Achei o issue na implementação do JBoss Wildfly (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-785) e ainda não foi resolvido. Acho que isso depende de cada Container, tente pesquisar se seu container consertou esse bug.

Comment: Na versão do Glassfish que estou usando (3.1) esse suposto bug persiste. Gostaria de saber se é prejudicial à aplicação deixar que crie vários beans em memória sem destruí-los, como é o caso do @ViewScoped. Uma solução que encontrei foi usar redirecionamento sempre que for navegar em outra página, daí sim o bean é destruído.

Comment: Como eu citei, vai haver o problema de memory leak, quanto mais `statefull` for seu Bean, pior. A solução que deu não é ruim, só não tenho certeza dos efeitos colaterais.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um *bean* do tipo **@ViewScoped** ficará ativo enquanto as requisições forem feitas para a mesma página. Quando você fizer uma requisição para outra página ou outro *bean* o escopo é limpo.

Quando se trabalha com JSF é muito importante conhecer bem os ciclos de vida. Não entendi bem quando você usa o termo "forçar" a destruição, mas creio que seria mais adequado usar um **@RequestScope**, que será criado no inicio de uma requisição e destruído no fim da mesma.

Não existe vantagem entre o **@ViewScoped** sobre o **@SessionScoped** pois ambos são usados para propósitos diferentes. Um *bean* do tipo @SessionScoped é instanciado uma única vez, que é quando um usuário inicia uma sessão no seu app e destruído quando a sessão é finalizada.

**EDIT**
Conforme citei em alguns comentários em outras respostas para essa pergunta, é muito importante separar os ManagedBeans por "conceito" (Ex.: PessoaBean, EnderecoBeam, etc...) para que o ViewScope lhe atenda corretamente. Caso precise acessar outros beans, lembre-se que é possível injetar um ManagedBean em outro, desta forma você não vai matar seu bean principal.

Comment: Se eu tenho um menu com dois itens, um dos itens eu direciono para pagina1 (action="pagina1") e no outro item eu direciono para pagina2 (action="pagina2"). Se eu entro na pagina1 e logo após eu entro na pagina2, o bean criado na pagina1 não é destruído. Sua afirmação sobre o bean ficar ativo até navegar para outra página não é 100% verdadeiro.

Comment: @Electus editei a resposta para ser mais claro. Mas o ManagedBeam só será destruído caso você faça um post para outra view.

Comment: Desculpa a ignorância, mas poderia me dar um exemplo na prática quando você diz "o escopo somente será limpo no caso onde a requisição para outra view seja feita através de um POST"? Estou estudando mais a fundo JSF a pouco tempo e tem coisas que talvez eu ainda não assimilei. Outra coisa: quando você diz pra usar @RequestScoped, acredito que vai depender da situação. No projeto que estou envolvido usa-se bastante AJAX e Dialogs como forma de simular um ambiente desktop. Com escopo request as "coisas" não funcionam adequadamente.

Comment: @Electus A afirmação causou mais confusão do que ajudou, até a retirei da resposta. Não tem muito o que se falar dos ciclos de vida pois eles são muito bem documentados. O que sugiro a você é que utilize o máximo do JSF e dos componentes. A implementação do JSF também faz diferença, prefira o Mojarra.

Eu lhe sugeri o request scope apenas para o caso de você necessitar limpar seu bean a cada acesso.

Comment: Edgar, obrigado pela atenção. Realmente há um bug (pelo menos penso que seja um bug) em relação ao @ViewScoped, pois ele não é destruído quando navego para outra página JSF, apenas se eu forçar um redirecionamento para outra página (já fiz vários testes e posso afirmar sem medo). Talvez o problema esteja relacionado ao servidor de aplicações que eu uso (Glassfish 3.1) e não ao JSF em si. Grato mais uma vez.

Answer (score 2):

> 1 - É problemático o bean nunca ser destruído e sempre ser criado toda vez que a página é acessada?

Coisas deste tipo são a razão que me faz não recomendar JSF para nenhum projeto novo.

Sim, há um avanço considerável na API e nas implementações, porém isso não vem acompanhando de solução para os problemas recorrentes do JSF.

> 2 - É válido eu forçar a destruição do bean usando redirecionamento?

Tudo é válido desde que cumpra a função necessário sem causar efeitos colaterais indesejados.

Infelizmente, quando usamos um framework que abstrai muito o funcionamento de um sistema web, muitas vezes temos de usar artifícios para conseguir fazer o *tuning* necessário.

Num sistema em que trabalhei, que usava JSF 1.1, tive que implementar uma rotina de limpeza de sessão cada vez que um menu era acessado. Isso porque o sistema era legado e os desenvolvedores tinham o hábito de colocar tudo em escopo de sessão. Não havia possibilidade de refatorar o sistema.

Basicamente, "interceptei" cada chamada a uma opção de menu para identificar quando o usuário saída de uma tela para outra. Então, percorria o mapa de sessão e removia as entradas, exceto algumas que eram realmente "globais". A diferenciação era feita com base em prefixos nos nomes dos atributos.

> 3 - Qual a vantagem do @ViewScoped sobre @SessionScoped nesse contexto?

O `@ViewScoped` tenta automatizar o cenário que descrevi acima. Ele funciona bem em uma tela que usa sempre Ajax para efetuar as operações.

Porém, um simples CRUD com telas de pesquisa, inclusão, alteração e exclusão não consegue fazer uso desse recurso. Para começar, se o usuário faz uma pesquisa e altera um elemento, todos os filtros são perdidos.

No fim você percebe que usar a sessão melhora a usabilidade no sentido de que alguns valores são necessários que fiquem armazenados para o usuário. Por outro lado, usar a sessão também gera problemas porque o usuário pode abrir múltiplas abas e janelas e o comportamento do sistema acaba se tornando imprevisível.

E, ao contrário do que pode parecer, o escopo de *View* gera a mesma coisa. Se o usuário abrir várias abas com a mesma página, uma delas irá alterar o estado das demais. Algumas pessoas pensam que o *View Scope* resolve os problemas do JSF, mas ele apenas minimiza alguns e na verdade causa outros.

Como consequência você acaba com requisitos de uso no mínimo estranhos como: *o sistema não pode ser usado em mais de alguma janela ao mesmo tempo*.

No fim das contas, a conclusão a que se chega é que uma usabilidade razoável só é alcançada com o escopo de requisição (*Request Scope*). Só que aí perde-se completamente a vantagem de um framework *component based* como o JSF. Inclusive vários componentes (pense no `dataTable` do PrimeFaces) deixam de funcionar corretamente com o escopo de *request*. E mesmo o que funciona acaba dando tanto trabalho como se você tivesse fazendo as coisas "na mão".

E, com tudo isso, concluí-se ainda que desde o início deveria ter sido usado um framework *action based*.

Comment: _"Porém, um simples CRUD com telas de pesquisa, inclusão, alteração e exclusão não consegue fazer uso desse recurso. Para começar, se o usuário faz uma pesquisa e altera um elemento, todos os filtros são perdidos."_ Esta afirmação só é verdadeira quando o desenvolvedor não sabe trabalhar com a tecnologia. Trabalho com JSF a anos e posso lhe afirmar isso.

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck Se o CRUD não é Ajax e o escopo é de View, o sistema vai perder as informações do cadastro. Soluções são manter o filtro em escopo de sessão ou então armazenar manualmente de outra forma. O que você geralmente faz?

Comment: O bean só vai ser destruído caso você acesse outra página por POST ou acesse outro ManagedBean. Geralmente eu tenho um managed bean por "conceito".

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck Entendo, mas aí você não pode, por exemplo, ter uma tela de alteração ou inclusão separada que faça *POST*. E se o sistema tiver um subcadastro? Ou ainda uma popup com filtro de pesquisa?

Comment: Você pode usar o mesmo bean ou pode injetar outros beans também, depende do problema. O viewscope funciona muito bem, basta utiliza-lo sabendo como ele funciona. Claro que não existe bala de prata.