# Executar um método na ManagedBean ao inicializar a Página

Tags: jsf

Saudações Pessoal.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma jeito formal de executar um método na ManagedBean ao invocar/inicializar uma página?

Eu já tenho feito isso, normalmente colocando a EL diretamente na página, antes de qualquer outro elemento JSF, e eu sinto(desconfio) que não é a forma correta de fazer.

Ex:
Suponhamos que existe uma página de registo de pessoas, e sempre que a página é carregada, eu preciso imprimir um texto no lado do server.

O que eu tenho feito é algo como:

```
...
<html ...>

    <h:head>
        ...
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            #{beanTeste.imprimirNome()}
            ...
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Grato desde já.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saudações pessoal.

A melhor solução que encontrei(sem querer dispensar a ajuda já aqui apresentada) é a utilização do tipo de evento `preRenderView` para a tag `f:event`.

Permite a execução de método durante o início da fase de resposta da apresentação(página JSF), ou seja, antes da página ser apresentada ele dá a possibilidade de executar uma tarefa.

Ex:

```
<html ... xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"> 
    <f:event listener="#{beanTeste.imprimirNome()}" type="preRenderView" /> 
    <h:body>
        ... 
    </h:body> 
</html>
```

Maiores detalhes:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844526/when-to-use-prerenderview-versus-postconstruct
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_event_handling.htm

Óptmo exemplo:

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-prerenderviewevent-example/

API:

https://javaserverfaces.java.net/docs/2.1/vdldocs/facelets/f/event.html

Answer (score 3):

Existe uma anotação que se encaixa exatamente no seu caso.

Use a anotação [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) para definir um método que é executado assim que o `ManagedBean` é construído (conforme o ciclo de vida do seu `Bean`), isso é, quando a primeira `EL` que referencia o `Bean` é encontrada.

Por exemplo:

```
@ViewScoped
// ou
@RequestScoped
@Named
public class MeuBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void inicializar() {
        // Sua logica de inicializacao
    }
}
```

Existe também a [`@PreDestroy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html), semelhante ao `@PostConstruct`, é chamado quando um `Bean` vai ser destruído. A chamada varia em relação ao escopo do seu `Bean` (a chamada depende do ciclo de vida). Se você usar um `Bean` com escopo de `View` existe um bug na maioria das implementações que não chamam esse método do ciclo de vida corretamente.

Essa pergunta [predestroy-em-viewscoped](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30562/predestroy-em-viewscoped) aborda esse comportamento.

---

Como seu `Bean` é de sessão, o `@PostConstruct` só é chamado uma vez, independente de quantas vezes ele é acessado em sua página.

Sabemos que o servidor de aplicação gerencia o ciclo de vida dos `Beans`. Logo ele irá criar e destruir seu bean de sessão. Irá criar na primeira referência a ele e  irá destruir quando a sessão for invalidada, guardando-o na sessão nesse meio tempo.

Tenho duas sugestões para resolver o problema, que seriam:

1. Substituir o Bean de sessão por um `@ViewScoped` ou `@RequestScoped`, e "cachear" o resultado do processamento que ele faz ou usa na sessão. Usando o `@PostConstruct` para imprimir o que precisa no console. Isso é válido se o seu `Bean` de sessão não for mais necessário após essa substituição.

   Porque em questão de gasto de memória, é até mais vantajoso que o `Bean` de sessão por guardar apenas o resultado e não o Bean inteiro. Porém em termos de organização e OO, o Bean de sessão se sairá melhor pois haverá um "contexto" em volta dos dados, toda lógica em relação a esses dados ficará centralizada em um só lugar. No caso, a escolha vai depender bastante de como esta sua organização.
2. Criar um Bean `@ViewScoped` ou `@RequestScoped` e injetar o seu Bean de sessão  para usá-lo no `@PostConstruct`. Em termos de código seria algo assim:

   ```
   @RequestScoped
   @Named
   public class MeuBeanDeImpressao {

       // Injeto o Bean de sessão
       @ManagedProperty("#{beanTeste}")
       // ou
       @Inject
       BeanTeste beanTeste;

       @PostConstruct
       public void inicializa() {
           beanTeste.imprimirNome();
       }
   }
   ```

   Esse caso só é vantajoso se você ainda precisa do Bean de sessão, mas pode usar um Bean de `@RequestScoped` ou `@ViewScoped` em sua página (tendo uso para outras coisas, senão poderá gerar gasto de memória desnecessário). `@RequestScope` se sai melhor por não existir o bug no ciclo de vida, será destruído após o uso.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Wakim. Apenas fiquei com uma dúvida: Se for uma MB do escopo de Sessão, este método será executado todas as vezes que a página for invocada/inicializada?

Comment: Não, ele só invocado na primeira vez que ele é referenciado (criado).

Comment: Bem então o erro foi meu, não fui tão explícito. Eu gostaria de executar sempre o método toda hora que a página fosse invocada, vou editar a questão.

Comment: É, essa solução só atenderia se o seu Bean fosse `ViewScoped`.

Comment: Exato! Na mesma obrigado pela dica, deu sempre para aumentar o conhecimento de uma possibilidade.

Comment: @ColdHack, vou colocar algumas alternativas pro seu caso em breve, só eu voltar em casa.